# Pycharm doesnt show output

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run the following code in Pycharm 2018.1.1 communtity :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv')

data.Speed.plot(kind = 'line', color = 'g',label = 'Speed',linewidth=1,alpha = 0.5,grid = True,linestyle = ':')
data.Defense.plot(color = 'r',label = 'Defense',linewidth=1, alpha = 0.5,grid = True,linestyle = '-.')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')     # legend = puts label into plot
plt.xlabel('x axis')              # label = name of label
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.title('Line Plot')            # title = title of plot
```

So when I press the run button to run the file pokemons.py it is just show the message: `Process finished with exit code 0` and doesnt output any plot (which is what the above code suppossed to do).

Comment: Please state a question.,

Comment: @S.john kindly accept the answer if helped u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it helped me while had the same problem

```
plt.show(block=True)
plt.interactive(False)
```

or alternatively only add

```
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `plt.show()` after your lines. [pyplot tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) can be useful.